# How to change default user for psql command

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql

When I run the command 'heroku pg:psql' it tries to authenticate me under 'justinwong'. This is a problem because that is not a user in the list of roles when I run \du command in postgres.

The only user that exists should be postgres.

How do I modify the default user that the 'heroku pg:psql' or 'psql' command tries to log me in with so that it's postgres rather than justinwong?

Comment: Can you set environment variables?

Comment: `heroku pg:psql` should use user configure for the database application uses, `psql -U username` is different - it will let you specify user with `-U` key

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps others as it helped me. [I found the answer in this thread posted by the OP](https://superuser.com/questions/1671646/changing-default-user-for-postgresql-on-windows-10) but a_horse_with_no_name alluded to this. Pretty much set an environment variable PGUSER to the user name you choose:

- Right click on Windows icon and click “System”
- Scroll down to “Advanced System Settings”
- Click Environment Variables
- In “System variables”, click “New”:
- Variable Name: PGUSER
- Variable Value: postgres